# In my shell, how do I use a for statement with input?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop, echo

Here is my code

```
bash-3.2$ read num
100
bash-3.2$ for k in {1..$num}
> do
>    echo Printed $k times
> done
{1..100}
bash-3.2$ echo $num
100
bash-3.2$ echo $k
{1..100}
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is doing this? It isn't the variable `num` that's wrong because I checked that with my `echo` at the end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, for some reason that doesn't work as syntax...

```
bash-3.2$ read k
100
bash-3.2$ read i
1
bash-3.2$ for (( c=$i; c<=$k; c++ ))
> do
>     echo -n "Printed $k times"
>     sleep 1
> done
Printed 1 times
Printed 2 times
...
Printed 99 times
Printed 100 times
```

[Click here for more on `for` syntaxes in scripting languages.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-iterate-over-a-variable-range-of-numbers-in-bash/)

Comment: The reason is that brace expansion occurs before parameter expansion; brace expansion requires literal values.

Answer (score 0):

The `for .. in ..` construct is for looping through lists of strings, not looping a number of times.  You want the `for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 ))` construct.  Try this:

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= $num ; ++ i )) ; do
  echo Next: $i
done
```

Comment: This works to :) It's just the approved answer sounds more like my java syntax, so is the one I'll probably be using more, nevertheless I +1'd your post

Answer (score 0):

how about this;

```
for k in $(seq 1 $num)
do 
  echo Printed $k times
done
```

Comment: nice and simple, thanks! I +1'd your post

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
for k in $(seq $num)
do 
  echo Printed $k times
done
```

Comment: nice and simple, thanks! I +1'd your post